# why pipe and sed print with args akward statement?

Tags: bash, shell, sed, pipe

The statement below should print `afc abc` but it prints `abc abc` instead
I tried many times but every time same result
Don't know why this happens could anyone explain and help me?

```
echo abc|xargs -i{} echo $(echo {}|sed 's/b/f/g') {}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, it is not clear, please mention more details in your post and do let us know. eg--> sample input and expected sample output.

Comment: If you use `echo abc|xargs -i{} echo {}|sed 's/b/f/g'` it will print `afc`

Comment: This makes it even more mysterious!  `echo abc|xargs -i{} echo $(echo '{}bbb' | sed 's/b/f/g')`

Comment: that's the problem it prints `abc` instead of `afc`

Comment: It's actually fairly simple. The command substitution is expanded **before** `xargs` is invoked. `echo {} | sed 's/b/f/g'` will do absolutely nothing and will expand back to `{}` and `xargs` will then be invoked like this: `xargs -I{} echo {} {}`. That's why you see the same text twice. You can see this behavior in @jas' comment. The substitution will get expanded to `{}fff` and `xargs` will be invoked like this: `xargs -I{} echo {} {}fff`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use as `sh -c` in xargs like:
`echo abc|xargs -i{} sh -c "echo {}|sed 's/b/f/g'"`